# how to save text in textbox in flatfile?

Tags: c#

I develop an C# application with GUI and I keep some logs in textbox. When user clicks save button, folderBrowserDialog opens. User choose a directory and click ok. MessageBox is appeared including a message that "saved to the file...". Operation is completed.

**All these I said happen, but** ***there is no file in the directory*** **that user specifies.** When I use neither **TextWriter** object nor **File.WriteAllText(..)**, I am always failed. Is there something wrong in the code below?

```
private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // create a writer and open the file
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath + "logFile.txt");
            // write a line of text to the file
            tw.WriteLine(histTxt.Text);
            // close the stream
            tw.Close();

            //File.WriteAllText(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath + "logFile.txt", histTxt.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Saved to " + folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath + "\\logFile.txt", "Saved Log File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you were to not specify a folder location, would you get the file to appear?

Comment: Look up a folder - it seems that you're writing it to c:\some\pathlogfile.txt, not c:\some\path\logfile.txt as per the messagebox.  You might want to take a look at [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Are missing a backslash in `new StreamWriter(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath + "logFile.txt");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) to create/add file paths, like this:

```
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath, "logFile.txt"));
```

This will add the path seperator of the current OS if needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating streams, please use using clause to automaticly dispose the resources. If you would like to create the file:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path)) 
    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
       tw.WriteLine(histTxt.Text);
       tw.Close();
    }
```

That code should works, and release the lock, that File.Create method creates on file.